# Does circular GC work in a map?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

I have a `User` object which strongly refers to a `Data` object.

If I create a `Map<Data, User>` (with Guava `MapMaker`) with weak keys, such a key would only be removed if it's not referenced anywhere else. However, it is always refered to by the User object that it maps to, which is in turn only removed from the map when the Data key is removed, i.e. never, unless the GC's circular reference detection also works when crossing a map (I hope you understand what I mean :P)

Will `User`s+`Data`s be garbage collected if they're no longer used elsewhere in the application, or do I need to specify weak values as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GC doesn't detect circular references because it doesn't need to.

The approach it takes is to keep all the objects which are strongly referenced from root nodes e.g. Thread stacks. This way objects not accessible strongly (with circular references or not) are collected.

EDIT: This may help explain the "myth"

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/thinkinginjava/abitaboutgarbagecollection.html

> Reference counting is commonly used to explain one kind of garbage collection but it doesn't seem to be used in any JVM implementations.

This is an interesting link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp10283/

Comment: That's interesting. Where does the myth of circular reference detection come from then? Is that what other GC's do, or an older version of the JVM (HotSpot)?

Comment: Edited to help explain the "myth" ;)

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom There's no myth really. GC can collect cycles of references, but not by any special processing. Java GC has always worked this way. Reference counting doesn't really qualify as GC at all.

Comment: @EJP, There does appear to be a belief that some JVMs might use reference counting, but I am not sure where this comes from.  It would be nice if the Java Spec excluded it as an option.

Comment: Anyway, just to check, this means I'm ok using just weak keys, right?

Comment: You should be ok without using WeakReference.

Comment: Hmm, but then how would entries ever become garbage? I never explicitly delete them, I'd just like them to be removed if the corresponding 'User' is not available in the rest of the system any more (which happens outside my control).

Comment: In that case, I agree you need weak references. But not because you have circular references.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation you see:
weakKeys()
Specifies that each key (not value) stored in the map should be wrapped in a WeakReference (by default, strong references are used).

since it is weakReferenced it will be collected.

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html

Comment: I know that, but this situation is more complex because my values also refer to the keys.